# Use Tempfile twice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing, nokogiri, open-uri

I'm having an issue with a simple program over what I believe has to do with Tempfiles. I am using 'open-uri' and 'nokogiri' and am trying to do a regex search on a document as well as an xpath search with nokogiri. However, it seems I cannot do this without making two seperate requests for the document and thus creating two separate Tempfiles. This works, but is making two requests:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

source_url = "http://foo.com/"
#grab html document and assign it a variable
doc = open(source_url)
#grab html document, convert to Nokogiri object and assign to variable.
noko_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(source_url))

#create array of stuff. 
foo = noko_doc.xpath("//some element").collect { |e| e }
#create another array of stuff
bar = []
doc.each do |f|
    f.each do |line|
        abstract_matches = line.scan(/some regex string/)                                  
        unless abstract_matches.empty?
            abstract_matches.collect! do |item|
                if item.to_s.match(/yet another regex string/) 
                    item
                end
            end.compact!
            unless abstract_matches.empty?
                abstract_matches.each { |match| bar << "#{ match } / " }
            end
        end
    end
end
#all for this
puts foo + bar
```

I would prefer if I could pass the 'doc' variable into Nokogiri::HTML, as well as iterate over it. Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's uncommon to iterate a Tempfile. More common is to access like this:

```
html = open(source_url).read
noko_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
html.split("\n").each do |line|
  # do stuff
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parse HTML from a string, see [the tutorial](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html).

Couldn't you just put `doc` into a string and have Nokogiri parse from that?

Comment: Solved. Called doc.rewind before iteration. Can't find a lot of good documentation on it, but here is an example: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_Files_in_Ruby
.rewind brings you back to the first line of the file.

Comment: FWIW, I agree with Dave on this.  The tempfile doesn't really do anything but complicate things.  Also, you want to be very careful with open-uri... in our experience, in production, it leaves the temp file lying around, which filled our servers' hard disks.